# Getting 403 error when tunneling to remote server

Tags: http-status-code-404, postman, ssh-tunnel

I have a lab environment where I can do various operations(GET, PUT, DELETE etc).

I do these in Postman using a URL similar to:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8338/accounts
```

This returns JASON containing account information.

I can also get this information with the following curl statement:

```
curl https://1.2.3.4:8338/accounts -u admin:Jpassword
```

I now want to do it in a remore environmnet that I have to access through a jump server. I previously did something similar. I used SSH Tunnel Manager to create the connection. This is what it looked like. 1.1.1.1 is the jump server IP and 1.2.3.4 is the server I'm looking to connect to.

```
ssh -N -p 22 username@1.1.1.1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L 1.1.1.1:8080:1.2.3.4:443
```

I can then access through postman or my browser using the following URL:

```
https://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

I want to do the same with except I must specify port 8338. If I follow the same steps but use port 8338 instead of 8080 I get a 403 response when I try my url. If I change port 443 to 8338 I also get also get a 403.

I was wondering if this is likely to be an authentication issue or something I'm doing wrong with my tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

My problem was that I was using a wrong port. I should have had port 8338 instead of 443.

```
ssh -N -p 22 username@1.1.1.1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -L 1.1.1.1:8080:1.2.3.4:8338
```

Now I can connect with this URL:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8080/accounts
```